# 3) Sketch a single graph of a function f (x) which satisfies all of the following the limits, values, and derivatives.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, graphing-functions

[Here is what I have so far, but be careful and look out for the functions that are highlighted, those are derivatives.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4LNr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that the second condition is not satisfied by the function you sketched.

Comment: Everything im asking is in the picture I posted a link to

Comment: Your graph is not compatible with the condition $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 2$.  Since $f(0) = 2$, the function is not continuous at $x = 0$.